# How do I wrap integration tests that use TestServer in a database transaction?

Tags: entity-framework-core, xunit

Using xUnit and the `TestServer` from Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost, how can I wrap each test in a database transaction that can be rolled back after the test?

Here's how I create the `TestServer`:

```
TestServer = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

The `Startup` that's referenced there is the `Startup` from the web app project. In the `ConfigureServices` method in that `Startup` class I add EF like this:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<TrailsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

I could pull the `DbContext` back of services and store a static reference on the `Startup` class, but that seems pretty hacky. Is there any way I can instantiate the `DbContext` where I create the `TestServer` and somehow have the web app use that instead of the one in the `Startup` class?

Edit: I have tried instantiating another instance of the `DbContext` where I create the `TestServer` and using that context to delete and recreate the database before each test, but that adds about 10 seconds to each test's run time.

Answer (score 2):

Some advice: the simplest approach would be to destroy the test database at the end and recreate for each test run. This ensures no lingering test-to-test contamination.

But since you asked how, this can be done by extending Xunit. Xunit allows you to define custom test cases and test runners. A complete answer is hard to include in a SO answer. The simplest solution uses ambient transactions. (Danger! Ambient transactions can be tricky.) Xunit has a sample for a custom BeforeAfterTestAttribute that rolls back a transaction. https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/AutoRollbackExample. To use ambient transactions, turn off the default EF setting that throws if ambient transactions are present.(`optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer().SuppressAmbientTransactionWarning()`).

A more complicated, but better solution is to override `XunitTestCaseRunner` and inject a transaction into each test case, ensuring to rollback at the conclusion of each test.

Also, EF docs provides a sample of using the InMemory provider to test. You may find this useful. 
["Testing In Memory : EF Core Docs"](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/testing.html)